# Wordpress Contact Form Jittering & Not Submitting

Tags: wordpress, forms

I don't understand what's going on - used several different contact form plugins and it's the same problem every time. Whenever the form is filled out and I click submit, the page acts all jittery and freezey and then keeps popping back to the top. Anyone have any advice on how to troubleshoot this problem? Don't really know how to debug and such....

http://www.adivineweddingmadeeasy.com/contact/

Comment: Sorry but there are some security/privacy concerns with your question. How do we know you own the site and are not trying to spam the owner? In any case your question is to vague to be properly answered.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a minute looking at it but have not found a definitive answer yet, but it seems like something is up with your form control, particularly as it is defined within each field. I was able to get the form to behave when removing all of the wcpf7 form control classes.  Then again, simply removing them would not fix your problem because the form would not function as designed.

In case you want to try checking it out yourself, try right-clicking and selecting 'inspect element' or 'inspect' from the drop down menu.  It won't mean much to you unless you understand HTML but it is a start in terms of troubleshooting.

You easiest solution is trying a different form application to see if it works.